# Average order of $\phi(n)$

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, divisor-sum

**Theorem 3.7** of the book **Analytic Number Theory** by Apostol states:

$$\sum_{n\le x} \phi(n)= \frac{3}{\pi^2} x^2 + O(x\log x)$$

and then it claims : **Hence the average order of** $\phi(n)$ **is** $\frac{3n}{\pi^2}$.

But I don't understand it because if we do this:

$$\frac{1}{x} \sum_{n\le x} \phi(n)= \frac{3x}{\pi^2}  + O(\log x),$$
then it seems we get something else.

So, how is the average order calculated ? Why are we ignoring the term $O(\log x)$?

Any hint/help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: The term $O(\log(x))$ is not ignored. But it is asymptocally much smaller than $\frac{3}{\pi^2}x$. So everything is alright.

Comment: it says **order**, so you can push inside the $O()$ the linear term, which is stronger.

Comment: I see what you mean. With [this definition or average order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Average_order_of_an_arithmetic_function) it should be $6x/\pi^2$ such that when we do $\sum_{n\leq x}6x/\pi^2\sim 3x^2/\pi^2\sim \sum_{n\leq x}\phi(n)$. However, in his book, it looks like he is calling average order of $f$ to a function $g$ such that $\frac{1}{x}\sum_{n\leq x}f(n)\sim g(x)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt that Apostol uses a different definition for average order from the more widely accepted one. According to Hardy & Wright's, Ténenbaum's, and Montgomery & Vaughan's textbooks, we say that $b_n$ is an average order of $a_n$ if

$$
\sum_{n\le x}a_n\sim\sum_{n\le x}b_n
$$

Using this relatively more accepted definition, we have

$$
\sum_{n\le x}{6n\over\pi^2}\sim{3x^2\over\pi^2}\sim\sum_{n\le x}\varphi(n)
$$

This means that the average order of $\varphi(n)$ is $6n/\pi^2$. However, if the definition of Apostol is used, we have

$$
\frac1x\sum_{n\le x}\varphi(n)\sim{3x\over\pi^2}
$$

Consequently, Apostol's version of average order for $\varphi(n)$ is $3n/\pi^2$.

Comment: For what it's worth, I would call $\frac{6n}{\pi^2}$ the average order, and $\frac{3n}{\pi^2}$ the asymptotic size of the average (perhaps the "order of the average" in short). Anyway, definitely it depends on the definition.